ImportError in Views.py inside my django project
I am trying to import a function form a project I have made a few months ago, but I get a this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seleniumtrack'
I tried some things ChatGPT recommended and I tried to look things up on the internet, but unfortunately it didn't work.
This is how my files are ordered:
python/
├── seleniumtrack.py
└── tracklist/
├── manage.py
└── downloader/
└── views.py
I am trying to learn Django, but here is my views.py script:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
import seleniumtrack




class SearchTracklist(forms.Form):
    url = forms.CharField(label="Tracklist url")

class StartScraping(forms.Form):
    start = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="start")



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if "urls" not in request.session:
        request.session["urls"] = []

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StartScraping(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for url in request.session["urls"]:
                seleniumtrack.scrape(url)
        else:
            return render(request, "tracklist/index.html", {
                "form": form
            })
    

    return render(request, "tracklist/index.html", {
        "urls": request.session["urls"]
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchTracklist(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            url = form.cleaned_data["url"]
            request.session["urls"] += [url]
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("downloader:index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "tracklist/index.html", {
                "form": form
            })
    return render(request, "tracklist/add.html", {
        "form": SearchTracklist()
    })

Can somebody help?

You need to put the full path to import the function, is the seleniumtrack function in the seleniumtrack.py file inside the python folder? then you need to call the function like this "from python.seleniumtrack import seleniumtrack"

it's always good practice to make utils directory in django apps directory or main project directory for util functions you can import functions in two way in django
Full path:
import directory_name.file_name.function_name

or relative path:
import .file_in_current_directory.function_name


Can you give an example if I have a folder called python, where seleniumtrack and a folder called tracklist are in. In tracklist there is a folder called downloader, and in downloader there is views.py

question python directory is in your main directory of your django project? or outside?

Python is the folder where i store all my projects, and in the folder is the folder called tracklist, which is the django project. Inside tracklist is a folder called downloader, this is the app. In downloader is views.py (seleniumtrack.py is in the python folder)

OK do as what i say create directory in tracklist name it utils after that move or copy seleniumtrack.py file to it after that from your view.py you can access it with import utils.seleniumtrack

Thank you it worked. Sorry I am just new to this stuff.

no worries we are here to help each other
